# Why use a single variable as a conditional evaluation?

Tags: c#, variables, conditional-statements

In my way of understanding conditionals throughout programming, whether it be an if statement, while loop, etc - a particular statement is checked as either true of false.

This is how I normally use conditionals, but I often come across other people's code  containing strange conditionals where there doesn't seem to be a particular evaluation, just an ordinary variable. For example:

```
someType aVariable = someValue;

If (aVariable) 
{
 //do this
}
```

What would be evaluating as true, or false, in this case? Obviously if aVariable represents a bool, that would be straightforward, but usually the explicit value isn't a bool at all, and often contains NULL. Once again, I'm seeing this in nearly every language I've looked at so I am assuming this is not language specific.

**EDIT 1**: as I've been made aware that this may be dependent on language, I will add that I see this very often in C#, and the variable in question can be either a reference type or a value type.

**EDIT 2**: all very good answers, which I have summarized below:

(a) it is language specific whether or not a particular non-bool variable may be evaluated as a bool
(b) in many cases, if the language supports such an evaluation, any non-zero, non-empty, or non-NULL value typically evaluates as TRUE (C/C++ int's)
(c) for languages that don't support such implicit evaluation, a cast to bool needs to be added in the class definition, for example (C#)

Comment: I am certain that the nuances depend on the language.  In php, that `if` statement would evaluate to `true` if: `aVariable` contained a boolean true, a string of any length, an array with any non-empty elements, an object with any non-empty elements, or a number other than zero.  If `aVariable` contained `false`, a string of no length, the number 0, an empty array, an empty object, or `null`, the if statement would evaluate to `false`.  This is also true in javascript.

Comment: You can't do this in C# unless `aVariable` is a `bool` or has an implicit conversion to `bool`.

Comment: Lee - I can't vouch for he veracity of this example but here is a reference to it in C# atleast. See code near bottom -  http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/439308/create-fading-sprite-in-c.html

Comment: @StevenNikolic - Yes, it looks like they have provided an implicit conversion to `bool` in their base `Object` class. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other answers have pointed out, the details are language-specific. In C# you can only do this if `aVariable` is a `bool` or has an implicit conversion to `bool` (or implements the `true` and `false` operators).

In your `Unity` link, it appears their base `Object` type has an implicit conversion to bool which returns whether the object is null e.g.

```
public class Object
{
    public static implicit operator bool(Object b) { return b != null; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the programming language.  For example, in Groovy any expression can be evaluated as a boolean and there are rules for how that evaluation takes place.

```
// groovy code
if(someVariable) {
    // do something
}
```

In that code the `someVariable` can be anything at all and it is valid Groovy.  The rule is that there are specific things that evaluate to false and those include the boolean false, the number zero, an empty collection, an empty String and null.  Everything else is true.  There is more to it but digging into that would be a bunch of Groovy specific stuff and I am just illustrating an example.

Not all programming languages have that kind of behavior.  It is up to the language designer to decide how all of that works.

Answer (score 2):

That only works in C# if `aVariable` is either already a boolean, or implicitly castable to a boolean.

In other languages - most notably C and C++ - integers can be used in this context. If they're equal to 0, the are `false.` Otherwise, `true`.

Pointers work the same way - since NULL is (mostly) equal to `0`, doing something like

```
float *ptr = null_ptr;

if(ptr)
{
/// will not be executed
}
```

And so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer David, as mentioned in my comment above to Lee, would this example be implicitly cast to bool, and if so, how do I determine that - http:/answers.unity3d.com/questions/439308/create-fading-sprite-in-c.html

Answer (score 2):

In a many languages, the value of variables other than a Boolean type can be evaluated as a true or false condition. In C/C++, for example, values that evaluate to 0, such as an `int` containing `0`, or a null pointer, evaluate to false. All other values are evaluated as true. For example, an `int` value:

```
int foo = 5;
if (foo)
{
    // This code gets run
}
```

In other languages, such as C# and Java, this behaviour is prohibited - the code above would cause a compilation error, as you are required to provide a Boolean expression as a conditional (an equivalent in this case being `foo != 0`).

There are good reasons for this. Subtle bugs can be introduced by allowing a value other than a Boolean to be evaluated as a condition. In the `if` above for example, an engineer may have intended to write `foo >= 0`, but was distracted before they finished. In C#, a compilation error would have drawn their attention to the error. In C/C++, the body of the `if` would be run if `foo` was less than *or greater than* 0. No compiler error is generated, as it is legal code, and a bug is introduced.

Comment: I gotta ask: distracted before they finished?

Comment: No, this was my answer. I answered before edits were made to the question that narrowed its scope. Initially, it seemed to be a general question about how data types other than `bool` can be used as conditionals (and didn't specify C#). When it was edited, it became clear that the OP was really asking about implicit conversion in C#. Well, Lee's answer sorts that. I didn't want to edit my answer to include redundant information, but I didn't feel like deleting it, as it still seemed to have some value.